# AVPlayer how to manage different URL

Tags: ios, avplayer

I'm trying to do a small radio app and I got a list of URL that I pass to AVPlayer but I can't understand how to manage different URL.

As example if I first play this URL: http://www.example.com/file.mp3
then I call http://www.example.net/file2.mp3
it works fine but when I select http://www.example.org/file.mp3.m3u it doesn't load that URL and AVPlayer won't play.

This is the code I use:

```
urlStream = [NSURL URLWithString:mp3URL];  
appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];    
playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:urlStream];
playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
[appDelegate.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
```

I use `replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:playerItem` because if I use `initWithPlayerItem` when I choose another stream I just can't stop the previous play: so the only way to stop the playing stream and start another one is to use `replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem`.

In the Apple documentation I read that `replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem` must have the same "compositor" as the items it replaces: what's a compositor?

I see that what it's different between the first two streams and the third (in the example above) is the file extension.

Any suggestion where to look for would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears not to be the replacing of items - but the file format of particular files. Try to open the m3u file first - probably it will fail as well.

The m3u-URL indicates that this not an mp3 file but a m3u file - that's a list of URLs to media files. `AVPlayer` and `AVPlayerItem` are capable of playing m3u8 files - that are m3u files which are UTF8-encoded.

Have you tried opening those URLs in Mobile Safari? If they don't work there the format probably is not supported by `AVPlayer` either.

In any case - if you could provide the actual problematic URL one could check the actual file format.

With "compositor" the "Quartz compositor" is meant - forget about that, not relevant here.
[Edit: maybe it is relevant - I'm dumbfounded after you comment to this answer ...]

Comment: First thank you. The m3u file is a valid path, I can open with the browser but more if I select first the m3u file from the list it works fine on the App but then when I choose the mp3 file again it will not work.

So the m3u extension works fine both on the browser and the App (as first choice).